# Zuul Connections not kept alive when using a Client Cert

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

To be able to support a client cert, I extended 
`ProxyHttpConnectionManager extends DefaultApacheHttpClientConnectionManagerFactory` and have overridden newConnectionManager

```
if (disableSslValidation) {
        try {
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadKeyMaterial((new File(keystore)), keyStorePass.toCharArray(), keyStorePass.toCharArray())
                    .loadTrustMaterial(new File(trustStore)).build();
            registryBuilder.register(HTTPS_SCHEME, new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.warn("Error creating SSLContext", e);
        }
```

Thats the only customization I have done. Zuul does not keep the HttpConnections alive for servers that need a client cert. For all other servers on Https, previous connections are reused.

**Summary for SSL Logs and TCP Dumps**

*No Client Cert requried*
`SYN` , Client Hello 
Server Hello 
Data Exchange
Request 2- Data Exchange
Close after timeout

*Servers with Client Cert Required*
`SYN` CLient Hello
Server Hello
Data Exchange
FIN
Request 2 - SYN
Hello's again
Data Exchange
Fin